# How to make a request to the grouping of results by date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can not write a valid request to obtain such a result (group recording day):

> date (days) - sum (field1) - sum (field2)
>
> date (days) - sum (field1) - sum (field2)
>
> etc.

My code:

document has_many downloads

download belongs_to document

```
@downloads = Download
    .order(created_at: :desc)
    .includes(:document)
    .joins(:document)
    .where('documents.uploaded_by = ?', params[:user_id])
    .page(params[:page])
```

I would be grateful for the help

**UPD:**

```
create_table "document_downloads", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "document_id", null: false
    t.integer  "payment_sum"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
end
```

i want to group like:

```
payment_sum   created_at
150           2015-06-27
120           2015-06-27
```

Answer (score 0):

I need more information about your table schema but this can be helpful..

```
Download.select('date(days), sum(field1), sum(field2)')
        .joins(:document)
        .where('documents.uploaded_by = ?', params[:user_id])
        .group('days')
        .page(params[:page])
```

Comment: Ok, this will be probably database specific query, which database system are you using now? Postgresql?